# How long is the year of the planet Vulcan in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Does anyone know any other information about the length of the Vulcan year in various *Star Trek* productions?

I have a problem with the length of the Vulcan year, so any additional data related to it would be useful.

Comment: You've done a huge amount of research here. Can I suggest that you move all of this question except the first and last paragraphs into an **answer** below? It's great info definitely worthy of an answer, and if someone else does find more info, you can always accept their answer to place it above yours.

Comment: Why did you write out the numbers? It takes up a lot of space in this already long q

Comment: After some consideration, I've removed the bottom portion of your "question". A lot of it is just making the same point repeatedly (complete with long, unneeded quotes) and the final few paragraphs seem to be trying to equate Vulcan to a real-world star system.

Comment: Addressed [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=8v9BjSQZJ10C&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=%22a+vulcan+year%22&source=bl&ots=tCGzsj5zqH&sig=ACfU3U0rx6Q47eai_Db0fMBFbgKMR3DH1Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAiOj73PnyAhVMwQIHHQqRC-EQ6AF6BAg3EAM#v=onepage&q=%22a%20vulcan%20year%22&f=false). In short, there's nothing in canon and what's in the EU is a big jumbly mess

Comment: “I have a problem with the length of the Vulcan year” — you hear that, Vulcan? We ain’t scared to say it, your years are vague as hell.

Answer (score 6):

Vulcan's sun is usually identified as [40 Eridani A](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/40_Eridani_A).  (Memory Alpha link)

Real world scientists have identified a planet in that system in the habitable zone, and probably fitting the description of Vulcan.

It has a period approximately equal to 42 earth days.   (insert your own Douglas Adams reference)

[Information here](https://www.universetoday.com/140045/astronomers-find-planet-vulcan-40-eridani-a-right-where-star-trek-predicted-it/).

Comment: Is there any indication that the writers of the *fictional* Vulcan had any idea that this was the case?

Comment: Gene Roddenberry stated Vulcan is orbiting 40 Eridani A so implicitly he accepted what that star's habitable zone was -which can be calculated far easier than observing a real planet.  Of course whether anyone else writing for Star Trek uses real world science is another matter. http://www.projectrho.com/vulsun.htm Gene's 1991 letter to Sky&Telescope magazine.